# add remove class with time limit with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a search box that should only show when an icon is clicked. 
After the box appears when an icon is clicked it should disappear in some interval of time (like 5 seconds), even when user clicks on the other part of the body.

```
$(".icon").click(function()){
    $("search-box").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I guess if search box is focused, it should not disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```js
var box = $(".search-box");

// Code for closing if anywhere else is clicked
$(document).click(function() {
  box.removeClass('active');
});

$(".icon").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // preventing parent click handler 

  box.addClass("active");
  // Adding class to the box

  setTimeout(function() {
    box.removeClass('active');
  }, 5000)
  // Code for removing class after 5 second
 
})

box.click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // preventing parent click handler 
});
```

```css
.search-box {
  display: none
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="icon">click</button>

<div class="search-box">Box to display</div>
```

Comment: when i click on the search-box it disappears. I am not able to write any on the box

Comment: Hello, Pranav. I have another question too but i am not able to post it before 90 minutes is over.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

**Jquery**

```
var icon = $(".icon");
icon.click(function () {
    $(".search-box").addClass("active");
    setTimeout(function () {
        icon.fadeOut();
    }, 5000)
})
```

Comment: what else do i have to add not to let the searchbox disappear when i am typing into it, it might take more than 5sec. and more importantly i am only able to open the searchbox once after it disappears i am not able to open it again, have to refresh the page.